# c# code to fire a keyevent when the condition is true.

Tags: c#

For an example, I have a project (c#) which gives output from 1 to 5 numbers. And if that was one, I want the program to write 'A' in note pad. I didn't use FORM to create my project in c#. It's written in XML. So, May i know how could i do this.?

Like, i tried - SendKeys.Send("{A}"); when the event is fired. But as my project is not a form. I couldn't do it. Can anyone help me on this. :(

Thank You.

MY ACTUAL PROJECT: 
I have done with emotion recognition. I have done with Second life emotions. I want to input the emotion detection in (C#) to second life. Only this is left. If I have had clarified my doubt, I could do it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In order to put "A" into the NotePad you can do

1. Find out NotePad Edit Window (assuming notepad.exe is executing)
2. Send WM_CHAR message to the window found

The code can be like that 
Required Native API declarations:

```
  internal delegate Boolean EnumerationCallback(IntPtr handle, IntPtr parameter);

  [DllImport("User32.dll",
             CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi,
             EntryPoint = "EnumWindows",
             CharSet = CharSet.Unicode,
             SetLastError = true)]
  [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
  internal static extern Boolean EnumWindows(EnumerationCallback lpEnumFunc, 
    IntPtr lParam);

  [DllImport("User32.dll",
             CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi,
             EntryPoint = "EnumChildWindows",
             CharSet = CharSet.Unicode,
             SetLastError = true)]
  [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
  internal static extern Boolean EnumChildWindows(IntPtr hwndParent, 
    EnumerationCallback lpEnumFunc, 
    IntPtr lParam);

 [DllImport("user32.dll",
            CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi,
            EntryPoint = "GetClassNameW",
            CharSet = CharSet.Unicode,
            SetLastError = true)]
  internal extern static int GetClassName(IntPtr hWnd,
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] 
    StringBuilder name,
    int size);

  [DllImport("User32.dll",
             CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi,
             EntryPoint = "GetWindowThreadProcessId",
             SetLastError = true)]
  internal static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, 
    out IntPtr ProcessId);

  [DllImport("User32.dll",
             EntryPoint = "SendMessageW",
             CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi,
             SetLastError = true,
             CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
  internal extern static IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr handle,
    int message,
    IntPtr wParam,
    IntPtr lParam);

  const int WM_CHAR = 0x102;
```

The solution itself:

```
public void PrintA() {   
  IntPtr handleNotePad = IntPtr.Zero;   
  IntPtr handleNotePadEdit = IntPtr.Zero;

  // First, find NotePad Main window   
  EnumWindows(
   (IntPtr h, IntPtr p) => {
     int processId;
     GetWindowThreadProcessId(h, out processId);

     if (Process.GetProcessById(processId).ProcessName != "notepad")
       return true;

     handleNotePad = h;

     return false;
    }, 
    IntPtr.Zero);

  // Second find NotePad EDIT window as a child of NotePad Main window
  EnumChildWindows(handleNotePad,
    (IntPtr h, IntPtr p) => {
       StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
       s.Length = 500;

       GetClassName(h, s, s.Length);

       if (s.ToString() != "Edit")
         return true;

       handleNotePadEdit = h;
       return false;
    }, 
    IntPtr.Zero);

  // Finally, send the message
  SendMessage(handleNotePadEdit, WM_CHAR, (IntPtr) 'A', IntPtr.Zero);
}
```